# In search for the part on the picture (freehand circled in yellow)

Tags: identification, repair

I'm on the hunt for the yellow circled component. I ripped it off after opening the toothbrush
and changing the bad on/off button. Sadly i have few clues what it does:It is connected with the charging process of the brush. When on the charger it signal that it is loading (flashing light) but in reality the battery does not charge.
I tried to find it on http://www.s-manuals.com/smd
and with https://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/smd-codebook.pdf
but could not narrow it down in the slightest.

[image: Insides from the a Phillips Sonicare Diamond Clean]

Comment: why can't you reattach the old component?

Comment: Sadly i lost it in the oping process and only figured it out after noticing that the battery was not charging (reassembled). The Foto is from Ifixit.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow circle is close to label Q3.

That part might be a dual transistor. That is 2 identical transistors in the same package.

Comment: Thanks a ton! (talk about hidden in plain sight. I knew R... resistor, C... capacitor... facepalm)
Top left and bottom left (Fotoperspective) are connected to ground.
Can it be a double schottky transistor? The A0 marking checks out with https://www.sphere.bc.ca/download/smd-codebook.pdf     (p 29)

Comment: I've never seen a Schottky transistor in my life. It may be a double bjt transistor.